# AWS AppConfig relationship between configuration profile & environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, app-config

We are planning to use AppConfig for our ECS/Lambda based applications, going through the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-deploying.html It seems deployment to an environments are made from a particular configuration profile (versioned).

Our applications have different configurations for each of the environments so does this mean we should have different configuration profiles as well for each of the environments?

I also looked into few examples and none of them have multi-config/environment deployments.